# Resizing GridView on different rotations

Tags: android, android-layout

just working on a simple layout and I was wondering if there was a way to automatically re-size a gridview?

My vertical rotation view looks like:

[image]

But my horizontal rotation view looks like:

[image]

The code for my layout at the moment is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="baegmon.mesmerize.GameActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Timer"
    android:id="@+id/textView_Timer"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Score"
    android:id="@+id/textView_Score"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Question"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/textView_Question"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_Timer"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_Question"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView_Game"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="5"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent = "true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any way to automatically resize in the Horizontal View so that all of the GridView fits inside of the layout? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Create two layouts for this one is for normal and another for landscape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem not in GridView size but in GridView **cell** size.

All cells cannot to fit into screen because of height of every cell is more then needed to fit by height of GridView. Thats why GridView makes your content scrollable.

Just try to change cell size.

Futhermore your cells scretches by width because of `android:stretchMode="columnWidth"`, this is the reason why in second case you have big horizontal spacing between cells.

Try to delete or replace that line.

Comment: I actually fixed it by creating a separate layout for the horizontal view as suggested by @Nigam_Patro and then I did what you wrote and also modified one line `android:verticalSpacing="-8dp"` which solved the issue.